# Copy a jpg file to another folder bash script unix

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

The code I have written has some errors:

```
cd OS2/OS22
for f in *.jpg
do
     cp -v "$f" OS! "${f%.jpg}"
done
```

It says: cp: target 'photo' is not a directory.
*Can someone please advise how can I correct the code, or if there is a different way/code to implement the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the path to ../../OS1

```
#!/bin/bash
cd OS2/OS22
for f in *.jpg
do
  cp -v $f ../../OS1
done
```